# Creating grid annotations (reference grid) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules, annotation

How do I make grid annotations like shown below in QGIS (v3.x)?

Sequential alphanumeric characters in the centre of grid lines. These are widely used in tourist maps and are sometimes refered to as [reference grids](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/grids-and-graticules.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_52CD2ABE5768414A82AD85FA95135399).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of tourist maps use this kind of annotation scheme with a reference list at the bottom stating which places of interest are located in which grids (Examples [here](http://www.surveyofindia.gov.in/files/ddun.compressed.pdf) and [here](http://www.surveyofindia.gov.in/files/chennai_f.pdf)). To add sequential alphabets or numbers as annotations at the centre of the grid lines, 3 grids need to be added to QGIS Map Item Properties

1. For the grid lines
2. For the annotations on latitudes
3. For the annotations on longitudes

For example, I am taking an area around Dehradun, India (approximately 30°19'N 78°02'E) and projecting the grids in CRS UTM 44N WGS84 i.e., EPSG:32644. The grid lines will be placed at an interval of 5000m (5km) and the annotations at exactly half of that distance i.e, 2500m. The screenshots are from QGIS 3.14.15-1 on Windows 64 bit.

The first grid should be set to the following options. This will add the grid lines. Ensure that the line style is thin / grey.

[image]

The second grid will add the annotations at the centre of the latitudes. The options are as shown. The idea of the custom script is to convert the `@grid_number` variable to an alphabet. The numbers will change for a different area.

[image]

Applying the same logic for annotations at the centre of the longitudes. Here the custom script will convert the `@grid_number` variable to a number. The numbers will change for a different area.

[image]