# Creating grid left to right not top to bottom

Tags: vector-grid, grids-graticules

I'm fairly new to QGIS having used mainly ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro to do things.

I'm trying to create a grid and label A1, A2 A3...B1, B2 and so on.

I've created the grid ok and worked out the labelling but it labels A1, A2 and so on down the first column however I want it across the top row then second row starts B1.

The labels however follow the ID numbers which go down first column and then onto the next.

Is there a way to create the grid so the id numbers read across the rows and then down or can I create the labels to not follow the id direction and go across rows?

Comment: Do you mean in the "Print Layout" ? Check out this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373480/creating-grid-annotations-reference-grid-using-qgis

Comment: I'm just in the main page where once you've loaded qgis you just choose start new blank template

Comment: Is the grid for a small area or a fixed area?

Comment: so the idea is to just create the grid for an incident anywhere in the state for mapping purposes for that incident. can be a small or large area so easier to create for each incident that arises.

Comment: I will put an answer then we will elaborate from there

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Grid Tool in "Vector" ---> "Research Tools" ---> "Create Grid" Tool

[image]

Use the right extents you need to use with the grid size.

[image]

You can click on the button on the right to generate the extents of your grid based on the map extents.

[image]

Once you have generated the Grid, you can save the temporary layer to any format you want then open the table.

[image]

Column index and row index are filled automatically.

You can then use then select a row and apply the Field calculator to append your cell number to a new column that you can use for your work.

[image]

You just need to select the row or column then calculate based on the selected features. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps for that, I was playing around and realised I was on an older version. I upgraded and those extra columns are there and when I add labels if does it across the rows rather than down so all good thanks. Turns out just a version thing.